# Port Number of a Web Application on SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-application, port

How can I extract a specific web application port number using Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
    {
        Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "PSSnapin SharePoint is now ON" -ForegroundColor Green `n
    }
else{
    Write-Host "PSSnapin SharePoint already ON" -ForegroundColor Magenta `n
    }
$web = Get-SPWebApplication http://YOUR_WEB_APPLICATION
# $web.IisSettings["Default"] #Most of the settings
# $web.IisSettings["Default"].ServerBindings #HostHeader and Port number
$web.IisSettings["Default"].ServerBindings.Port #Only Port number
```

Comment: @Suhayl Bhat, please mark it as answer if this is what you asked for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Below command should return the details in url property:

> Get-SPWebApplication | Select DisplayName, Url

This will return all the web apps with in the server farm.