# New Web App: Cannot access root Site Collection

Tags: root

I've created a new test farm. I have the default Web Application and Root Site Collection that were created with Config Wizard which I can browse perfectly fine at sp16-01.vanguard.com:

[image]

If I create a new Web Application, using default settings & authentication (NTLM), with a new Root Site Collection with a name that I want e.g. white.vanguard.com:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm unable to browse the Root Site Collection. I message that is returned is:

"Server IP address could not be found"

I've tried the following with no success:

- Adding an A record in DNS to point white.vanguard.com to the WFE IP,
- Enabled Anonymous Access,
- Giving Full Control in User Policy for the Web Application

When I add the A record in DNS I am prompted for authentication but none of my accounts work (SPFarm, SPAdmin, Administrator).

I'm missing a step here. Could someone please enlighten me?

EDIT: Added screenshots below for AAM, DNS, IIS and Hosts file. As mentioned this is out of the box. I've tried A record and CNAME in DNS, AAM entries, bindings and hosts file entry but cannot get the site to load.

EDIT2: I'm trying to browse the site from the WFE.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What authentication scheme do you use? Kerberos or NTLM?
 Did you create a new site collection inside the new Web app?

Comment: @Evariste I've updated my post. I did create the Site Collection and the authentication is default NTLM

Comment: You'd also need to add white.vanguard.com as an Alternate Access Mapping (as a public address). However I'm not sure this is the actual problem here.

Comment: @Evariste An AAM to what though? After the SC is created an AAM entry is already created for http://white.vanguard.com to http://white.vanguard.com. This is an out of the box farm so there has been no changes to the default configuration.

Comment: The AAM is already there because you created the Web app directly with the name white.vanguard.com, OK, as per the new screenshots you posted. However, why did you use port `34535`? I'd expect `80` if you wanted the complete URL to be `http://white.vanguard.com` and not `http://white.vanguard.com:34535`.

Comment: What does "Get-SPSite -Limit All" return in SharePoint Management Shell

Comment: @ben here you go
`Url | CompatibilityLevel
http://sp16-01 | 15
http://white.vanguard.com:34535 | 15`

Comment: @ben Added some more screenshots to the original post.

Comment: @Rubio Are you trying to access the site collection from the server itself or from some other machine? If trying from the SP-Server you might need to either DisableLoopbackCheck (not recommended) or add white.vanguard.com(:34535) to the BackConnectionsHostnames in Registry. For both see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926642/error-message-when-you-try-to-access-a-server-locally-by-using-its-fqd

Comment: yes i'm accessing it from the same server. i'll try this when i get home, thanks!

Comment: @ben mate you are a genius! it was because i was trying to browse to the site from the wfe itself. i created a new win10 vm, added it to the domain, created the A record in DNS and it connected to the site without issue. please post this as an answer and i'll accept it as the correct answer

Comment: I will post it as an answer for others to see as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments it showed that you are trying to access the site-collection `http://white.vanguard.com:34535` locally from the web-frontend server itself.

Windows Server prevents such back connections, that is accessing locally hosted websites via other hostnames than `localhost` or the server's "real" hostname (here `sp16-01`) or FQDN.

In such cases you have to add the desired additional FQDN (here `white.vanguard.com`) to the list of allowed BackConnectionHostNames in the windows registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`. If there is no entry `BackConnectionHostNames`, you have to create it as multi-string value.

Alternatively, you can completely disable loop back checking by creating the DWORD-entry `DisableLoopbackCheck` with value 1 under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`. But beware that this is not recommended as it disables a security feature.

Comment: This is precisely the step I was missing! Thank you! In addition to this registry change you would also need to add a hosts file entry: 127.0.0.1 white.vanguard.com

Answer (score 1):

As per the screenshots you posted, the new Web application you created is hosted on port `34535`, making the complete URL `http://white.vanguard.com:34535` and not `http://white.vanguard.com`.
You should have created the Web application on port 80 to be able to browse it with `http://white.vanguard.com`.
Either delete and re-create it on port 80, or try to update the current port from 34535 to 80 with PowerShell (here is the PowerShell code to *read* the port number, you can aybe adapt it to *set* the port number: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/150967/35604).

Comment: Even if I browse to `http://white.vanguard.com:34535` there is no success. Referencing the first screenshot, if I delete the other Web Application on port 80 and create a new white.vanguard.com WA & SC on port 80 again there is no success. The error in Chrome is: `white.vanguard.com’s server IP address could not be found ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Let's assume the error message tells the truth (which I believe): there's most probably a DNS error. Can you try pinging white.vanguard.com? What's the result?

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Administrator> ping white.vanguard.com`
`Ping request could not find host white.vanguard.com. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: If I add a hosts file entry for the server IP and the host header (10.0.0.198 white.vanguard.com) I will be prompted for a password when I browse to the site. However the password prompt just keeps looping.

Comment: Added some more screenshots to the original post.